# Does Satan have access to Heaven?

Tags: job, satan, heaven

Does satan have access to visit heaven??
What does Job chapter 1 refer to satan has come to heaven along with the Sons of God?

Comment: Which of the three? He has access only to the first two, up to the clouds and from the clouds to the firmament, he cannot cross the firmament

Comment: Is satan still have that access ?

Comment: There is no mention of heaven in that passage; not even when referring to the sons of Elohim presenting themselves to Elohim.

Comment: @Joel "Is satan still have that access ?" What access? Heaven? Love for you to quote Job 1 in that regard. Which is what you should do. If you think Job 1 says that somewhere. Edit your question, and include a quote ... and of course, you can't do that. "And **again** the anger of the Lord was kindled against Israel ..." 2 Samuel 24:1

Comment: @david, why you quoted 2 Sameul 24:1 here,  how does this is related to satan being  there at the presence of God with the angels ??

Comment: @Joel These questions have been asked and answered abundantly. Hopefully, you ask out of ignorance, and not with malice. But my anger is firmly directed toward those who allow the distortion of scripture to flourish. Bonus points gained by reading the parallel account to 2 Samuel 24:1 in 1 Chronicles 21:1 and noting that yhwh is labelled satan, or the adversary. Welcome to Jesus, enjoy your stay. It is through much tribulation that you will enter the kingdom **of** the heavens.

Comment: But I'm Australian. Obviously a moron.

Comment: @davidianwalker That’s a terrible “reading” of 1Chronicles 21:1 or rather misrepresentation. The fact that you can’t wrap your head around the truth and have an agenda invalidates your claims, which goes without saying is wrong. I’m Australian too, has nothing to do with intelligence, as it’s not tied to nationality.

Answer (score 1):

We know Satan has access to heaven for Job 1:6 tells us Satan and his angels entered heaven and “presented themselves” to the Lord. Now there was a day when the sons of God came to present themselves before the LORD, and Satan also came among them.

Revelation 12:7-10 KJV

> <sup>**7**</sup> And there was a war in heaven: Michael and his angels fought against the dragon, and the dragon fought and his angels, <sup>**8**</sup> and prevailed not; neither was their place found anymore in heaven. <sup>**9**</sup> And the great dragon was cast out, that old serpent, called the devil, and Satan, which deceiveth the whole world: He was cast out into the earth, and his angels were cast out with him. <sup>**10**</sup> And I heard a loud voice saying in heaven, Now is come salvation and strength, and the kingdom of our God, and the power of his Christ; for the accuser of our brethren is cast down, which accused them before our God day and night.

This shows us that up until this happens, Satan does have access to heaven, where he accuses God’s people before the throne as seen in the book of Job 1:6-12 and Revelation 12:10:

Comment: Up-voted +1 but I notice you are not stating _when_ the transition occurred of Satan having access to heaven and then Satan being cast out by Michael and his angels. (Which, I appreciate, is a matter of interpretation and I respect your restraint.)

Comment: Considering there are three, your response is at best ambiguous, it actually stands to conflate and confuse the reader the way you have worded your response. Satan has only ever had access to the first to heavens and still currently only has access to the first two. The judgment seat heaven is in the second heaven. You could make a case that after the resurrection the judgment seat has been moved to the third heaven, maybe.

Comment: "Job 1:6 tells us Satan and his angels entered heaven ...". Really? Really? Jesus wept.

Comment: @david, what do you mean by Jesus wept?

Comment: This person has "answered" your question regarding Job 1 'Does Satan have access to Heaven?' with 'We know Satan has access to heaven for Job 1:6 tells us Satan and his angels *entered heaven* and “presented themselves” to the Lord.' They then proceed to apparently quote said verse 'Now there was a day when the sons of God came to present themselves before the LORD, and Satan also came among them.' Note carefully, **that verse doesn't state or hint heaven is involved in any way shape or form**. Note that carefully. A confident assertion in the affirmative but no substance at all. To what end?

Answer (score 0):

```
Does Satan have access to Heaven?
```

Never did, never will.
And of course Job 1 and 2 agree with that.
It's kind of understood, that when asking a question about a bible topic or any other topic for that matter, that one would read the material. Not "my drunk friend said" or "I saw on the Simpsons" or some other nonsense.
Conclusions drawn from such sources, invariably provide excuses to avoid christianity as nonsense.

> **Every** *kingdom* divided against itself will be ruined, and **every** *city* or *household* divided against itself **will not stand**.
>
> Matthew 12:25 NIV

This is a truism for **all**.
Further, as the one *kingdom* and *city* and *house* that will stand **forever** the last place we find dissent is within god's *kingdom* and *city* and *house*.

God's *kingdom*, *city*, *house*, all emanating **from** him, to endure and stand **forever** on the earth **in the future**.

> ... the God of heaven will set up a *kingdom* that will never be destroyed ... it will itself endure forever.
>
> Daniel 2:44 NIV

> My Father’s *house* has many rooms ... And if I go and prepare a place for you, I will come back ...
>
> John 14:2-3 NIV

> I saw the Holy *City*, the new Jerusalem, coming down out of heaven from God ...
>
> I did not see a temple in the *city*, because the Lord God Almighty and the Lamb are its temple.
>
> **Nothing impure will ever enter it, nor will anyone who does what is shameful or deceitful** ...
>
> Revelation 21:2,22,27 NIV

And finally :

> ... your kingdom come,
> your will be done,
> on earth as it is in heaven.
>
> Matthew 6:10 NIV

God's will is done in heaven perfectly.
The father *dwelling* in **unapproachable** light, that dwelling being heaven.

> God, the blessed and only Ruler, the King of kings and Lord of lords, who alone is immortal and *who lives in **unapproachable** light*, whom no one has seen or can see.
>
> 1 Timothy 6:15-16 NIV

*Until* that future time, when that *kingdom*, *city*, *house*, are manifest on the earth, **out of** heaven, **from** god, *the divided house* is fully and firmly here, on this planet.

> For **everything in the world**—the lust of the flesh, the lust of the eyes, and the pride of life—**comes not from the Father** *but from the world*. The world and its desires pass away, but whoever does the will of God lives forever.
>
> 1 John 2:16-17 NIV

> Your slanderous adversary, as a roaring lion, is **walking about**––seeking to devour: Whom resist, steadfast in your faith, knowing that, the same sufferings, in your brotherhood that is **in the world**, are being accomplished.
>
> 1 Peter 5:8-9 Rotherham

The slanderous adversary - διάβολος - i.e. the "devil", is walking about on the earth. QED.

> And Yahweh said unto the accuser, Whence comest thou? And the accuser answered Yahweh, and said, *From going to and fro in the earth, and wandering about therein*.
>
> And Yahweh said unto the accuser, Whence comest thou? And the accuser answered Yahweh, and said, *From going to and fro in the earth, and from wandering about therein*.
>
> Job 1:7,2:2 Rotherham

The notion that someone like Cain or Judas, or Peter on a bad day, can somehow magically appear in heaven to converse with deity is absurd. An embarrassing wresting of Job 1 and 2 and the bible generally.
Absurd **and** offensive.

The father's name is **holy** for a reason.

```
... satan has come to heaven along
with the Sons of God?
```

Likewise.
Job 1 and 2 give no indication that any actors are anywhere other than on the earth.

In the period between the ejection from Eden and the establishment of the proto-typical kingdom and city of god in Israel and Jerusalem, deity interacted with men directly through the fellowship of elohim.

Obviously with Adam and Eve, in the beginning :

> Then the man and his wife heard the sound of the Lord God as he was *walking in the garden* in the cool of the day ...
>
> Genesis 3:8 NIV

Obviously also with Enoch before his death :

> After he became the father of Methuselah, Enoch *walked faithfully with God* 300 years and had other sons and daughters.
>
> Genesis 5:22 NIV

In this period, leading up to the flood, this walking or administration, was not only personally with the faithful, styled the "sons of god" but also uniquely with the wicked, notably Cain himself :

> Then the Lord said to Cain ...
>
> Then the Lord said to Cain ...
>
> Cain said to the Lord ...
>
> Genesis 4:6,9,13 NIV

The removal of this personal administration between the sons of god and the wicked after the judgement of the flood being described here :

> And Yahweh said––My spirit shall not **rule** - יָד֨וֹן - in man to times age––abiding, for that, he also, is *flesh* ...
>
> Genesis 6:3 Rotherham

Here "flesh" having the sense of being corrupt. Even *with* the personal administration of elohim, Cain slew Abel, there were threats of further violence, and the sons of Seth intermarried with the daughters of Cain.
More pertinently יָד֨וֹן being to **administer**, or "judge", as with the outcome of Cain's transgression, and ultimately the judgement in Noah.

These interactions continuing in a lesser form after that judgement, deity appearing to Abraham, and so on, until the establishment of the proto-typical kingdom and city.

> Do not forget to show hospitality to strangers, for by so doing some people have shown hospitality to angels without knowing it.
>
> Hebrews 13:2 NIV

> Are not **all angels** *ministering spirits sent to serve those who will inherit salvation*?
>
> Hebrews 1:14 NIV

However, not only was there opportunity to "present oneself before the lord" directly ...

> In the course of time Cain brought some of the fruits of the soil as an offering to the Lord. And Abel also brought an offering—fat portions from some of the firstborn of his flock. The Lord looked with favor on Abel and his offering, but on Cain and his offering he did not look with favor.
>
> Genesis 4:3-5 NIV

... but presenting oneself to an appointee of deity, i.e. his priest, is considered throughout scripture to be functionally equivalent, and with the advent of Moses, served as replacement :

> Then the Lord said to Moses, “See, I have made you like God to Pharaoh, and your brother Aaron will be your prophet.
>
> Exodus 7:1 NIV

> Every high priest is selected from among the people and is *appointed to represent the people in matters related to God*, to offer gifts and sacrifices for sins.
>
> Hebrews 5:1 NIV

Not only the priesthood but likewise the tent of meeting and subsequently the temple :

> I have heard your prayer and have chosen this place for myself as a temple ...
>
> Now my eyes will be open and my ears attentive to the prayers offered **in this place**.
>
> 2 Chronicles 7:12,15 NIV

There is no indication anywhere in Job 1 and 2 that these ideas are not respected.
Either the adversary presenting themself together with the faithful, at some designated place, with or without priesthood, but more likely in accord with the nature of the narrative, elohim themself being present.
This latter suggested also by the chronology of Job amongst the patriarchs **before** the exodus and the Mosaic covenant and temple.

### A warning.

Be careful not to misinterpret the bible but also not to misrepresent it.
Job 1 and 2 do not hint or suggest anywhere in anyway that there is any interaction in heaven.
Certainly it is not stated.
To suggest otherwise is disingenuous.

Absolutely avoid **pedestrian nonsense** *such as quoting the prophetic section in the apocalypse* to rationalize doctrine in a manner that directly **contradicts all other bible instruction** on those points.
Don't want to be Judas ourselves do we?

> The Revelation of Jesus Christ, which God gave to him, to point out unto his servants the things which must needs come to pass with speed,––and he **shewed them by signs**, sending through his messenger, unto his servant John
>
> Revelation 1:1 Rotherham

Setting aside the poor translation :

> *No one has ever gone into heaven* except the one who came from heaven—the Son of Man.
>
> John 3:13 NIV

Suggesting that the faithful "sons of god" and/or the wicked have at any point been able to transport themself to the abode of the almighty for chit-chat is beyond lazy.

> ... some things that are hard to understand, which ignorant and unstable people distort, *as they do the other Scriptures*, **to their own destruction**.
>
> 2 Peter 3:16 NIV

Probably have to add malice in there alongside ignorant and unstable.
Some people just choose the darkness.

Happy hunting.